# wp8 dictionary<string,List<object>> resolved

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-phone-8

hi I'm new with wp8 I'm trying to develop an application . i have some problem to get from my 
dictionary i don't know what's wrong here is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < SharedInformation.tab.Length; i++)
{
    lsCategorie.Clear();
    for (int j = 0; j < SharedInformation.SharedLscitation.Count; j++)
    {
        if (SharedInformation.tab[i].Equals(SharedInformation.SharedLscitation[j].categorie.ToString()))
        {
            lsCategorie.Add(SharedInformation.SharedLscitation[j]);
        }
    }
    SharedInformation.dic.Add(SharedInformation.tab[i], lsCategorie);
}
```

and my call

```
lsCitation = new List<Citation>();
lsCitation = (List<Citation>) SharedInformation.dic["amour"];

listbox.DataContext = lsCitation;
```

my complete code

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Popup popup;
    private BackgroundWorker backroungWorker;
    ShareStatusTask quotesh = new ShareStatusTask();
    SmsComposeTask quotesms = new SmsComposeTask();
    List<Citation> lsCitation = new List<Citation>();
    List<Citation> lsCategorie = new List<Citation>();

    // Constructeur
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowSplash();

    }

    private void ShowSplash()
    {
        this.popup = new Popup();
        this.popup.Child = new SplashScreen();
        this.popup.IsOpen = true;
        StartLoadingData();
    }

    private void StartLoadingData()
    {
        backroungWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backroungWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backroungWorker_DoWork);
        backroungWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backroungWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backroungWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void backroungWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this.popup.IsOpen = false;

        }
        );
    }

    void backroungWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //here we can load data
        Thread.Sleep(9000);

        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("data") == false)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.DownloadStringCompleted += web_DownloadStringCompleted;
            string uri = "http://quotesconsommation.azurewebsites.net/json/json.php";
            web.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["data"] = 1;
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["citation"] = lsCitation;
            SharedInformation.SharedLscitation = lsCitation;
            MessageBox.Show("" + NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() + "");

        }
        else
        {
            SharedInformation.SharedLscitation = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["citation"] as List<Citation>;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < SharedInformation.tab.Length; i++)
        {
            lsCategorie.Clear();
            for (int j = 0; j < SharedInformation.SharedLscitation.Count; j++)
            {

                if (SharedInformation.tab[i].Equals(SharedInformation.SharedLscitation[j].categorie.ToString()))
                {
                    lsCategorie.Add(SharedInformation.SharedLscitation[j]);
                }
            }
            SharedInformation.dic.Add(SharedInformation.tab[i], lsCategorie);
        }
    }
    void web_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);


        foreach (var blog in rootObject.citation)
        {
            lsCitation.Add(blog);
        }
```

and where i'm making the call

```
 List<Citation> lsCitation;
    public TOUTES()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        lsCitation = new List<Citation>();
        lsCitation = (List<Citation>) SharedInformation.dic["amour"];

        listbox.DataContext = lsCitation;

    }
```

mu sharedinformation class

```
public static class SharedInformation
{

    public static Citation Sharedcitation;
    public static List<Citation> SharedLscitation;
    public static Dictionary<string, List<Citation>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<Citation>>();
    public static String[] tab = { "amour", "art et spectacle", "arts et creation", "bonheur", "cinema", "cultures", "famille", "fetes", "humour", "insolite", "livres et lettres", "musique", "nature", "philosophie", "pratique", "proverbes", "sagesse", "sciences", "sport et loisirs", "theatre", "travail" };
    public static bool connectionstatus;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `Clear()` on the `List<T>` - you need to make a new one each time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SharedInformation.tab.Length; i++) 
{ 
    // Make a new list, don't reuse it!
    lsCategorie = new List<object>(); 
    for (int j = 0; j < SharedInformation.SharedLscitation.Count; j++) 
    {
```

Since `List<T>` is a reference type (a class), each time you add, it doesn't add an entire copy of the list - it just adds the reference to the same list.  Next time through your loop, you clear out the *old* list and add new items to it, etc.

As such, the behavior you'll see is that every key will have the items from the *last* tab's items, since they're all the exact same `List<T>` instance.

Comment: still don't work !!
i'll explain more basically i'm getting all my information from an azure data base i'm using json to parse data and get the result in static list of object but i need to sort these object from certain attribute and put the result in a Dictionary to make the call easier

Comment: @user3084145 I tried to give you the specifics from your question - but there are far too many issues that could be problematic.  You'll need to run it under a debugger and check values as you pull them from Azure to see what's happening.

Comment: i'm getting all the data from the asure it's working fine but row